# how to make two left floated div vertically

Tags: css, css-float

hey i have a user info div that have user pic ,user name , user bio divs , now i want to user pic to left side and  Name & bio is other side ,

Html

```
<div class="user-info">
<div class="user-pic">
    <img src="" class="u-pic"/>
</div> 
<div class="user-name">Jon Doe</div>   
<div class="user-bio">I am a english teacher</div></div>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gL2d3qwn/1/)

After doing this all divs have same height but i want name div to be in top and bio div should in bottom of name div  .

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove float property from user-name class

```
.user-info {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #aaa;
  float: left;
    padding:15px
}
.user-pic {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
    margin-right:15px;
    background:blue;
}
.user-name {
  //float: left;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #333;
    margin-right:15px;
}

.user-bio{
  float: left;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #333;
}
```